# LWC Apex Refresh not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire, refreshapex

I have been struggling to understand why my HTML is not rendering Fresh Stream of Data using Apex Refresh. I've used the cacheable method in Apex.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static Max_Assessment__c getMaxAssessment(String CaseID{

    try{
        List<Max_Assessment__c > maxAssessRecord = [SELECT Id, BH_Other_Parts__c FROM Max_Assessment__c WHERE Case_ID__c = :CaseID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];                
        
        if maxAssessRecord () == 1){
            return  maxAssessRecord [0];
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

In JS, I've stored the entire response in "wiredMaxSafeRecord" property.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import getMaxAssessment from "@salesforce/apex/MaxAssessMentController.getMaxAssessment";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { updateRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";


import ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Max_Assessment__c.Id";
import PLAN_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Max_Assessment__c.BH_Plan__c";


export default class Bh_safetyPlanForm extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @track accessRecord;
  

  error;
  wiredMaxSafeRecord;

  @wire(getMaxAssessment { CaseID: "$recordId" })
  wiredgetMaxRecord(result) {
    this.wiredMaxSafeRecord= result;
    if (result.data) {
      this.accessRecord = result.data;
      
    } else {
      console.log(result.error);
    }
  }

  clearUnsavedData() {
    refreshApex(this.wiredMaxSafeRecord);
  }


updateMaxInformation() {
    const fields = {};
    fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.accessRecord.Id; 
    fields[PLAN_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector(
      "[data-field='planData']"
    ).value;
    
    const recordInput = { fields };

    updateRecord(recordInput)
      .then(() => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Updated",
            variant: "success"
          })
        );

        // Display fresh data in the form
        return refreshApex(this.wiredMaxSafeRecord);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error Updating Record",
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }
```

In Developer console under debug log I can clearly see that logs are generating once updateMaxInformation & clearUnsavedData function are invoked. But the values on the HTML are not renderning. Nor I'm able to capute debug log.

Edited

```
<template>
        <lightning-card>
            <template if:true={accessRecord}>
                                                  
                     <lightning-textarea label="Plan"
                            data-field="planData" value={accessRecord.BH_Plan__c}>
                     </lightning-textarea>
                                
                <!-- Buttons for Saving and Reverting  Changes-->            
                    <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Cancel" onclick={clearUnsavedData}> </lightning-button>

                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={updateMaxInformation}></lightning-button>
               
            </template>

            <template if:true={error}>
                {error}
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Please add the LWC template. Just [edit] the question to do so.

Comment: (I ask because I'm wondering what's gonna call `updateMaxInformation`. I'm also wondering why you do a "return" for `refreshApex` in that function.)

Comment: BTW, assuming that `result.error` is defined when `result.data` is undefined (in `wiredgetMaxRecord`) is incorrect. The very first call to your wire function will always receive a completely empty parameter value.

Comment: @PhilW, thank you I've updated the html code and also removed unnecessary code.

After playing around, I found out that  I'm actually getting a stream of data only when there is a change in the record from the Backend. For ex: if I update any field from Standard Tab and call refreshApex from Cancel Button, if actually render the latest data.

Comment: What I wanted here is if User has made any change on the form and they don't want to save it and rather they want to cancel it, form should set the value back by refreshapex. Eventually, I saw some links that apexRefresh only works when it notices any Data change. Could you suggest how can I implement this undo kind of functionality, maintaining the original value?

Comment: One simple option is to switch from using a wire to using imperative Apex. Another simple option is to clone the data you get back from the wire and use this clone in the editor, resetting the clone from the wire data on cancellation.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW for this idea. I'll follow this approach.